# JPA Cascaded Update/Delete of OneToMany

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have two entities "Article" and "Comments". Article has OneToMany relationship with Comment.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "article")
public class Article implements Serializable
{
    public Article()
    {

    }
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "article_id")
    private int articleId;
    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;
    @Column(name = "category")
    private String category;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "articleId", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "comment")
public class Comment
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public Comment()
    {

    }
    @Id
    @Column(name = "comment_id")
    private int commentId;
    @Column(name = "author")
    private String author;
    @Column(name = "text")
    private String text;

    @JoinColumn(name = "article_id", nullable = false)
    private int articleId;
}
```

I am using JPA EntityManager to perform CRUD operations on Article.

I have an article with the following data in the "article" table.

```
article_id         title        category 

     1       Java 8 in 30 days    Java
```

I have two comments with the following data in the "comment" table.

```
comment_id   author    text              article_id

    1         ABC     Java is awesome !        1
    2         XYZ     Nice Article !!!         1
```

Here is my EntityManager code which gets invoked when there is an update to an article including comments.

```
public Article update(Article article)
{
    return entityManager.merge(article);
}
```

The issue that I am facing here is that whenever I delete a Comment from an existing article using the above method call then the comment really does not get deleted from the table. I understand that "merge" is same as "upsert", but I did not find any other method in EntityManager interface to achieve the comment deletion **along with** other changes to article.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code, `@OneToMany(... cascade = CascadeType.ALL)` means that whenever a modification is done on the parent (persist, delete, etc.), it is cascaded to the children as well. So if an `Article` is saved, all its' corresponding `Comments` are saved. Or if an `Article` is deleted, all its' corresponding `Comments` are deleted.

In your case, what you want is just to delete a `Comment`, unrelated to operations that happen in its' `Article`.

An easy way to do that is use `@OneToMany(... cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)` and then when you decide to trigger `delete` on the first `Comment` for example, just use `Collection.remove()` on it:

```
Article article = ...;
//...
Comment targetComment = article.getComments().iterator().next();
article.getComments().remove(targetComment);
// now Hibernate considers `targetComment` as orphan and it executes an SQL DELETE for it
```

Make sure your collection is the only one holding a reference to the object referred by `targetComment`, otherwise you will have inconsistencies in memory.